# Voltar versão do aplicativo

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

É possível voltar a versão do app? Colocamos inicialmente no campo **Número da Versão** o número **2** apenas para ver como ficaria e depois disso não estamos podendo retornar à numeração que gostaríamos (0.1.0), o app dá o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `Número de versão` deve ser um valor inteiro, e deve ser apenas incrementado, ele é o que o vai ser usado para saber se deve atualizar o aplicativo e o Google Play nunca vai permitir você lançar um APK com o número repetido ou menor que o anterior, porém esse valor não é exibido em nenhum lugar.

No geral, sempre que for lançar uma nova versão no Google Play você deve incrementar em 1 esse valor, durante o desenvolvimento não precisa se preocupar com ele.

O `Nome da versão` você já pode colocar o valor que quiser, e pode aumentar ou diminuir a hora que quiser, esta é a versão que é exibida pro usuário.

Answer (score 3):

O problema ocorre porque esse número da versão não aceita o formato `x.x.x`, informe uma versão inteira, por exemplo: `10`.

Espero ter ajudado.